# Django F object and relativedelta years

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django ORM not working when I do querying like this:

`F('date_last') - relativedelta(years=1)`, it returns `None` for my field. But works with `F(date_last) - timezone.timedelta(days=365)`

So I'm using raw SQL that is working fine, except, that on testing I using `sqlite3` database that is not support `DATE_ADD` function. Any ideas how to support both: `mysql` and `sqlite3`

My query:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    expiration_date=Case(
        When(
            accreditation_cycle=Accreditation.ANNUAL_ACCREDITATION_CYCLE,
            then=RawSQL('DATE_ADD(date_last, INTERVAL %s YEAR)', params=(1, ))
        ),
        output_field=fields.DateField()
    )
)
```

Comment: Django did not implement functionality to parse `relativedelta`s.